# Using ServletContext in ServletListener

Tags: java, servlets, memory-management, servlet-listeners

I have created a web application using java language and Tomcat server. All the users should use a linked list that should be embedded into the memory of the server. I have developed a servlet listener and I want to know how I would add the linked list to the application memory. Would it be the same way used in servlets? `getServletContext().setAttribute(name,value)` and then all requests can use this application attribute.

Answer (score 0):

A static class like

```
public static GlobalLinkedList{

  public static LinkedList list =  new LinkedList();

  public static getLinkedList(){
    return list;
  }

}
```